# Static Bitmap set to null doesn't stay null

Tags: android, bitmap, static, null

In my app I have a profile pic of the user. If he previously logged in, I download it from my server, otherwise he takes a pic from the camera or gallery. Either way, I store it in a class called DataStorage in a static public Bitmap variable thus:

```
public class DataStorage {
.
.
    public static Bitmap origProfilePic; //not saved on app close
.
.
```

Now, if the user decides to re-do his profile, I log him out send him back to the profile creation screen, and I call:

```
    DataStorage.origProfilePic = null;
```

(By the way, null is a legitimate value for this picture - we allow users to have no picture). The profile creation is through 2 activities - first choosing a username and password, then choosing a picture and other details. What's weird is that although I  set the picture variable to null, somehow when I get to the end of the profile creation, it has gone back to it's original value, and I somehow have a user with the old profile picture (this is in the case where he did not select a new picture)

I've logged it n the OnCreate functions of the two activities:

```
onCreate SignUpActivity1, origPic = null
```

then

```
onCreate SignUpActivity2, origPic = android.graphics.Bitmap@42ba7438
```

But SignupActivity1 calls the intent for SignUpActivity2 and nowhere in SiugnupActivity1 is there a reference to DataStorage.origProfilePic except in my log statements.

I decided to check one more time in SignUpActivity1 if the value changes and I found...just as I invoke SignupActivity2:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity1.this, SignUpActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("EMAIL", email.toString());
    intent.putExtra("PASSWORD", password.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.e("Kibi", "End SignUpActivity1, origPic = " + DataStorage.origProfilePic);
    finish();
```

This somehow has:

```
End SignUpActivity1, origPic = android.graphics.Bitmap@42ba7438
```

This is quite repeatable in this specific case, though I certainly set the bitmap to null in other places and don't see it popping back up.

I saw a few things on SO about static Bitmaps being a danger for memory leaks, though I don't see a memory leak right now, I worry that I must be doing something very wrong if setting to null cannot be relied upon.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and what the best way is to store this Bitmap in a basically volatile way?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that both values change when you use `DataStorage.origProfilePic` in both activities. Since it's a static value, both activities are pointing to the same memory object.

`DataStorage.origProfilePic` is pointing to a piece of memory where your bitmap is stored. Assuming you use something like:

```
#SignUpActivity1
Bitmap origPic  = DataStorage.origProfilePic;

#SignUpActivity2
Bitmap origPic  = DataStorage.origProfilePic;
```

What happens here is that you create a reference to `DataStorage.origProfilePic`. That means you practically have the same value in `SignUpActivity1.origPic` and `SignUpActivity2.origPic`.

When you call this rule:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

The OnCreate method in SignUpActivity2 will be invoked. You probably will set here (or somewhere else) the value of `DataStorage.origProfilePic`, which means the value of `SignUpActivity1.origPic` and `SignUpActivity2.origPic` also changed (not entire true, but will have a different output).

Also be carefull with `DataStorage.origProfilePic = null;`. This only set the reference to `null`, but doesn't clear the bitmap from memory. Use `DataStorage.origProfilePic.recycle();` to clear the bitmap from memory.

Comment: Ah - I think the last bit about recycle may be what I am looking for - gonna test that now and will accept if it helps

Comment: Ahh, no - doesn't work sorry, not sure what's happening. I'm always using DataStorage.origProfilePic directly - not assigning another Bitmap to be equal to it...now when I I null it I try to recycle first, but doesn't seem to help

Comment: Still if you change the static value in `SignUpActivity2` the value in `SignUpActivity1` is changed to, since they use the same reference. It's not a good idea to create a static variable when you use the it for different purposes / meanings. It is true you change the value of  `DataStorage.origProfilePic` in `SignUpActivity2` right?

Comment: I only change it when someone takes a picture...but the specific bug I have is that no one is taking any picture, I am not hitting any lines which change DataStorage.origProfilePic and yet the value is changing...that's what I don't understand